# MSSQL_query in PHP Returning Diffrent Results than SQL Native Sproc

Tags: php, sql, iis

Anyone ran into this one before?

I have a Stored Procedure in SQL with the following Parameters :

```
    exec PaySummary 'DemoTest', 'DemoTest-Mohn-00038', '5/14/12', '5/27/12', 'manager', 'DemoTest-Boyd-00005'
```

And the following MSSQL Query in PHP running the exact same query.

```
private function dataTest(){
    $strSQL = 'exec PaySummary \'DemoTest\', \'DemoTest-Mohn-00038\', \'5/14/12\', \'5/27/12\', \'manager\', \'DemoTest-Boyd-00005\'';
    $a = mssql_query($strSQL);

    echo $strSQL;

    while($row=mssql_fetch_array($a)){
        var_dump($row);     


    }

}
```

When run in SQL for this query I will get 3 results...

When run in PHP through SQL I get 2 Results...

Is there any run time settings (Set NoCOUNT on) that you must set on a SQL Stored Procedure to ensure accuracy of the output of results?  Or is there a known issue with passing date parameters that would impact the results of a date driven stored procedure?

Microsoft-IIS/5.0 / PHP/5.2.5  / SQL Server 2008 R2 (Where the stored procedure is executed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone in this same situation...  It is caused by the NULL_CONCAT_NULL (or whatever) option in SQL.  This one flag can make a stored procedure run a little bit differently depending on how you use concat etc.  A good way to solve this problem is via an ISNULL around a lot of your items which seemed to get rid of the issue of getting different results.

Further another option if you do not want to fix your sprocs is to check the path that sql is going through (TCP/IP etc).  I noticed when watching the audits that some settings were wildly different depending on the port that sql was running through.